# Rock Paper Scissor Game Replay Part Bug = Even answer No as "N" returns to start

Tags: python

I wanted to break out of the game when the replay() answer is no as "N" but typing "Y" or "N" seems like it does not make any difference.This is my first post and sorry for any mistakes. I cant post the whole code for some reason

thanks

```
def replay():

    replay_answer = input("do you want to play again?: ")
    while replay_answer != "Y" and replay_answer != "N":
        input("do you want to play again?: ")
        if replay_answer == "Y":
            return True
        if replay_answer == "N":
            return False`enter code here`
        break

while True:

    wincheck()
    replay()
```

Comment: Why did you think this would act as you wish? You do nothing with the returned result of `replay()`...

Comment: You also want to remove the `break` statement. There's no point having the loop if you're going to break out of it there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why did you think this would act as you wish? You do nothing with the returned result of `replay()`...

Try this instead for the last loop:

```
while True:
    wincheck()
    if not replay():
        break
```

And as mentioned by @khelwood remove the first `break`:

```
def replay():
    while True:
        replay_answer = input("do you want to play again?: ")
        if replay_answer == "Y":
            return True
        if replay_answer == "N":
            return False
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
def replay() -> bool:
    replay_answer = ""
    while True:
       replay_answer = input("do you want to play again?: ")
        if replay_answer == "Y":
            return True
        if replay_answer == "N":
            return False
while True:
    wincheck()
    if not replay():
        break
```